# Railsアプリケーションが本番環境にてcssが効かずに困っています。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, aws, unicorn

Railsアプリケーションが本番環境にてcssが効かずに困っています。
テスト環境では正常にcssやimage,javascriptがその都度compileされて反映されますが本番環境ではなぜかcssだけが反映されません。
(assets:precompileは完了していて正しく読み込まれていますが、全く効かない状況です。)

試したこととして、

- assets:precompile実行後、app/public/assets配下に正常にファイルが生成されることを確認した
- app/public/assets配下を一旦creanした(なぜかコマンドからのcleanが効かなかったので手
  動でrmした)
- キャッシュを削除し念のためシークレット・ウィンドウからも試した
- Unicorn, Nginxを再起動した(エラーログは出ていない)
- テスト環境で反映されるか確認した(app/assets配下がその都度compileされ呼ばれています)
- app/public配下のパーミッションエラーを疑いurlから直接pathを指定して正しく見れることを確認した
- 生成されたソースを読み、余計なstylesheetが読み込まれて干渉していないか確認した
- http://qiita.com/metheglin/items/c5c756246b7afbd34ae2 に指摘されていることはすべて確認した

なお、環境は以下のとおりです。cssだけが読み込まれず困っています。
どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

- Rails 4.2.0
- Ruby　2.2.0
- rbenv 0.4.0
- Unicorn 4.8.3
- Nginx 1.6.2
- MySQL 5.5.40
- EC2 Amazon Linux AMI 2014.09.1 (HVM)（プロダクションマシン）
- Git（リポジトリマシン）

Comment: *正しく読み込まれています* とのことですが、ブラウザで確認したのでしょうか。Chomeで言えば、Developer Tools の Resources セクションや Sources セクション、さらには Network セクションで、意図通りにCSSが読み込まれていることを、確認されたのでしょうか?

Comment: テスト環境で確認したとあるのですが、developmentではなくproduction で確認されたのでしょうか？

Comment: Chromeのデベロッパーツールより、ResourcesセクションやSourcesセクションでも正しく渡されておりパスも正しい状態です（ステータスコードは200もしくは304になっています）。Unicorn、Nginx、ブラウザ含め特にエラーログも出ていない状態です。

Comment: テスト環境ではtest（app/assets配下が呼ばれます）、本番環境ではproduction（public/assets配下が呼ばれます）でUnicornをそれぞれ起動している状態です。

Answer (score 1):

当たり前すぎて確認済みかと思いますが、

```
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

このあたりの設定が <アプリケーションのルートディテクトリ>/config/enironments/production.rb
にて設定された上で

```
$touch <アプリケーションのルートディテクトリ>/tmp/restart.txt
```

と実行した後、tmp/cache の中身を削除してから webサーバーを再起動してみたらどうでしょうか。これでも動かないときに

```
rake assets:precompile
```

なども試していると大体うまく動いている気がします。
既にやってると思いますが、紛らわしいことにならないように、ブラウザのキャッシュは消去して、更新が反映されるまで何回かブラウザからアクセスかけてると表示が更新される、ということもあった記憶があります。
この辺、仕組みをきちんと把握してないので経験からだけでの回答になりすみませんが、お役にたてば。
プリコンパイルできたかどうかは、大抵のブラウザには表示されたページはそのソースが読める機能があるので、ソースを表示して、headタグのCSSファイルを読み込んでいる部分(linkタグ)のファイル内容を確認するのが手っ取り早いかと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘いただいている点ももちろん確認済みでありまして、それでも原因がまったく検討つかずで困っております。

precompile自体は正常に完了しており意図したディレクトリに格納され意図した内容にcompileされ、prodiction環境下にて適切に読み込まれてブラウザより呼びだされております（imageは反映されますがstylesheetは反映されない状態です）。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

[AssetSync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync)を使ってリソースをS3に持っていくのはどうでしょう？

バケットポリシーを適切に設定すれば、問題の切り分けに役立つと思います。

Answer (score 0):

私はpublic/assetsごと一旦rmして、もう一度precompileしたらcssが当たりました。
色々試したのですが、public/assets配下に.sprockets-manifestというjsonファイルがあってそれでprecompileしているファイルのバージョン管理を行っていると思うのですが、それが古くなっていたからだったのだと思います。
なので、一旦全部削除して再度やってみたらできました。もしご参考になれば幸いです。